# Wordpress : How to print the excuted sql right after its execution

Tags: wordpress

I am searching for a way by which i can print the executed sql query just after the  :

```
$wpdb->query(
                $wpdb->prepare("INSERT 
                                INTO tbl_watchprosite SET 
                                keywords=%s,url_to_post=%s,description=%s,
                                date_captured=%s,crawl_id=%d,
                                image_main=%s,images=%s,brand=%s,
                                series=%s,model=%s,condition=%s,box=%s,
                                papers=%s,year=%s,case_size=%s,status=%s,listed=%s,
                                asking_price=%s,retail_price=%s,payment_info=%s,forum_id=%d",
                                $this->getForumSettings()->search_meta,$element->href,$post_meta['description'],current_time('mysql'),$cid,$post_meta['image_main'],$images,$post_meta[0],$post_meta[1],$post_meta[2],$post_meta[3],$post_meta[4],$post_meta[5],$post_meta[6],$post_meta[7],$status,$post_meta[9],$post_meta[10],$post_meta[11],$this->getForumSettings()->ID)
            );
```

This would be great if i can see what values are going in the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running the following code right after your query to see what's happening:

`exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );`